# Service is not registered when configuring multiple Eureka hosts as comma separated

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have created two Eureka servers as primary and secondary. I have configured my service url in Micro services bootstrap.yml as shown below.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ilpproxy
# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.83.134.39:8761/eureka/,http://10.83.143.221:8761/eureka/
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${vcap.services.${PREFIX:}configserver.credentials.uri:http://user:password@localhost:8888}
```

My service is only registered in the primary Eureka and not listed in the secondary. If I configured the primary Eureka as the first value then service is getting listed in both Eureka instances.

Below is the application.yml of the Eureka

```
server:
 port: 8761
security:
 user:
   password: ${eureka.password} # Don't use a default password in a real app

info:
 component: Discovery Server

logging:
 level:
   root: WARN
   com.pearson: WARN
   com.netflix.hystrix: WARN
 file: /data/logs/eureka.log

eureka:
 client:
   registerWithEureka: false
   fetchRegistry: false
   serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
 server:
   waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
   enableSelfPreservation: false
 password: ${SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD:password}
 instance:
   hostname: 127.0.0.1

---
spring:
 profiles: peer # not standalone
eureka:
 instance:
   hostname: 127.0.0.1
 client:
   registerWithEureka: true
   fetchRegistry: true
   serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://user:${eureka.password}@127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/

---
spring:
 profiles: other # not standalone
server:
 port: 8762
eureka:
 instance:
   hostname: 127.0.0.1
   nonSecurePort: ${server.port}
 client:
   serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://user:${eureka.password}@127.0.1.1:8761/eureka/

---
spring:
 profiles: local # connect to remote peer
eureka:
 instance:
   hostname: ${localhost.hostname:${localhost.ngrok}.ngrok.com}
 client:
   registerWithEureka: true
   fetchRegistry: true
   serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://user:${eureka.password}@${PREFIX:}eureka.cfapps.io/eureka/

---
spring:
 profiles: zone_d # connect to remote peer
server:
 port: 8761
eureka:
 client:
   registerWithEureka: true
   fetchRegistry: true
   serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://10.83.143.221:8761/eureka/,http://10.83.134.39:8761/eureka/
 server:
  waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
 password: ${SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD:password}

logging:
 level:
   root: WARN
   com.pearson: WARN
   com.netflix.hystrix: WARN
 file: /data/logs/eureka.log
```

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was in the Eureka configuration. Due to the previous configuration used for Spring-boot 1.0, peer awareness was not functioning properly. Correcting application.yml as shown below solved the problem. Below setting is requesting each Eureka nodes to register with each other, allowing peer awareness to function properly.

```
server:
  port: 8761
security:
  user:
    password: ${eureka.password} # Don't use a default password in a real app

info:
  component: Discovery Server

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    com.pearson: INFO
    com.netflix.hystrix: WARN
  file: /data/logs/eureka.log

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.83.104.765:8761/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    enableSelfPreservation: false

---
spring:
  profiles: zone_d # connect to remote peer
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.83.33.109:8761/eureka/
  server:
   waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
   enableSelfPreservation: false
```